# Django Background Tasks autodiscovery not working

Tags: python, django, background-process

I have configured background tasks in my Django App according to docs. The structure of my app is as follows:

```
todo_app
    |
    task
    |   |
    |   models, tests, urls, admin, apps
    |
    |
    frontend
    |       |
    |       tasks.py
    |       |
    |       models, tests, urls, admin, apps
    |
    manage.py
    |
    |todo_app
            |
            settings, urls, wsgi etc
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
'background_task',
  ...
]
BACKGROUND_TASK_RUN_ASYNC = True
```

tasks.py:

```
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=1)
def task_runner(repeat=3):
    print("hello world")
```

`python manage.py process_tasks` runs the task when the method is invoked under some view. The issue is that if its invoked under a view it will be invoked way too many times and the repeat will unnecessarily overload.

What mistake am I making under the auto discovery? Is it necessary to manually invoke the method even after running `python manage.py process_tasks`? Thank you.

Comment: can you give us an example of what do you do in the background task?

Comment: I have a model called TodoTasks. In the background process I check which records have been soft-deleted by the user. I plan of running a background process every 2 weeks to hard delete records older than a month. So I have flag for soft -deletion. Every 2 weeks, the job would clear out the records.

Comment: then you need to keep the `python manage.py process_tasks` always running on the server in the background. And when the user deletes the task in the view, call `task_runner(<TodoTasks Id>, schedule=timedelta(days=14))` which will schedule the deletion at the same time 2 weeks from now. This answer assumes the user can't undelete/restore the deleted item.

Comment: I am able to do that right now. But my concern is invoking `task_runner` multiple times, so lets say I delete 5 items today, 14 days later the task invokes `task_runner` 5 times. But I want to schedule it only once. So the creation of the process must be independent of the view method. I assumed auto-discovery solved that issue and created tasks/jobs automcatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to run a [daily job](https://crontab.guru/once-a-day) to hard delete tasks deleted more than 14 days ago. You have 3 options to do that:

- Write your own [django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) and add it manually to a [crontab on the server](https://coderwall.com/p/k5p6ag/run-django-commands-using-cron).
- Use [django-cron](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)
- Use [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab)

Comment: what about on windows?